# Let P=C/{1} and Q=mod(z)>2 and f(z) is analytic on P, then there does not exists a non constant analytic function P to Q .

Tags: complex-analysis

Here domain is C/{0} and codomain is mod(z)>2 i have to claim that f(z) is constant , now my intuition is if i prove that f(z) has a Removable singularity at z=1(if exists) then it can be extended on C analytically so , f(z) can be redefine at the point z=1 , then by picard's theorem a function f(z) can leave atmost one value of Complex sets from it's range but here codomain is mod(z)>2 , so function has to be constant (plz tell if my intuition is correct) , now iam having difficulties to show why f(z) if singularity exists at z=1 is a Removable singularity , i know since f(z) is analytic on C/{1} so singularity if exists is an isolated singularity and isolated singularity is of 3 types - (1) removable , (2) pole and (3) is essential , if it has essential singularity at z=1 then in the deleted neighbourhood of z=1 f(z) can be made closer to any complex value ( and leave atmost 1) but codomain is mod(z)>2 so uncountable many points inside the disk mod(z)<=2 will not be in it's range so essential singularity is not possible, how can we say f(z) does not have have a pole but a Removable singularity ?? i know*from theory) if z=1 is a Removable singularity of f(z) at z=1 then f(z) is bounded in some neighbourhood of z=1 , but i can't able to see this.

Comment: This comment https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721920/zeroes-of-anlytic-function-is-isloated#comment5618890_2721920 to your previous question applies here as well ...

Comment: Do u have any problem ??? I have no teachers so iam expanding it , if iam wrong in something then tell me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider the function $ g(z) = \frac {1}{f(z)}$ . See that since |f(z)| > 2 ,  g is bounded around a neighborhood of 1 and hence it has a removable singularity at 1 . So g becomes an entire function with image contained inside the disk of radius 2 . So by $ \textit{Picard's Theorem }$ g must be constant . So f is constant .

Comment: Thank you  , any other way to think other than this , i got it .. simple explantion .

Comment: why we are looking singularity at z=0 here it is at z=1 .

Comment: That was a typo.Now I think it's ok.

Comment: In fact one doesn't need Picard's theorem here . Since g is bounded and entire g must be constant by Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: iam confused .. if i define g(z)=1/f(z) then f(z) is analytic on C/{1} then g(z) is also analytic on C/{1} except at the zeroes of f(z) , so not only 1 , but also zeroes of f(z) creating problem here codomain is mod(z)>2 so , 1/f(z) range will lie in the disk mod(z)<1/2 , so f(z) is bounded so all these problem creating points must be isolated singularities ?? so, g(z) can be extended to an analytic functions by redifining values at those points and then apply liouvelle's theorem ??

Comment: f does not have any 0 since the range is |z|>2 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75654/discussion-between-user534210-and-pranab-sarkar).